# Referencing data sent in an AJAX request

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

Suppose I am sending the following AJAX request using jQuery:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    async: true,
    url: '<?=$_SERVER['PHP_SELF'] ?>?date=<?=$date ?>',
    data: $('#dateform').serialize(),
    dataType: 'json',
    success: function (data) {
        alert('Successful for date ' + data['date']);
    },
    error: function (data) {
        alert('Error for date ' + data['date']);
    }
});
```

If the server passed back the 'data' element in the JSON, then all is good and it can be read for the alert.

However, if there was an error preventing a return of the date sent, how can the AJAX request detect which date value was sent within the error function? This is assuming the user selected a different date before the server had a chance to respond, so the `date` element in `#dateform` would no longer represent the date that was sent with the request.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Save the value of date into a variable before submitting the ajax post and reference the value of this variable inside the error function.

Comment: Thought of this, but then noticed users were changing the date and resubmitting the AJAX form before the previous process finished. This subsequently cause the variable value to be changed before the previous server side process was finished. This is behavior I want to allow, but account for, because the server side process is something that can run simultaneous for quite some time and shows the results as they become available in the user's view.

Comment: Just make sure the variable is local to the function initiating the ajax request, not a global variable.